# tbl_regression from package gtsummary

Tags: r, error-handling, datatables, summary, gtsummary

```
install.packages("gtsummary")
library(gtsummary)
```

> **Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gtsummary’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘glue’ 1.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 1.6.0 is required**

I am trying to use the function tbl_regression but every time I type library(gtsummary), I get this message and a failure. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There was likely an error during installation. Close all your R sessions, open a single R session with nothing loaded and try to install again

Comment: The error message seems quite informative. Have you read it completely and tried correcting the identified problem?